# Aiming for a more accurate and precise color replacer

Tags: c#, bitmap, hex, rgb

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

In my program, I want to let the user enter any image, then my program resizes it then it gets all of the pixels and checks whether their color matches the color of the pixel at (0, 0). If it does match that pixel then it's going to be replaced with a hardcoded color.

**The issue I'm having**

My code works when I try to resize and replace the pixel colors with new ones, however when replacing the pixel colors, it usually does not replace some of the pixels, especially those that are closest to the image itself where the colors begin to diverse.

**What I tried to fix the problem**

I tried declaring the HEX colors as a string and whenever the C letter came, I would tell the program to remove the pixel that string. However, I found that to be very inefficient due to how often it can replace pixels that shouldn't be replaced.

**My code**

```
public class PicGen
    {
        public PicGen(PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            Bitmap picBitmap = new(pictureBox.Image);
            Bitmap resized = new(picBitmap, new(52, 52));
            Color backColorBottom = resized.GetPixel(51, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < resized.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < resized.Height; j++)
                {
                       if (resized.GetPixel(i, j) == backColorBottom)
                        resized.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(54, 57, 63));
                }
            }
            Clipboard.SetImage(resized);
        }
```

Example: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzlFS.png) Notice how the white around the image isn't replaced like the rest of the background? ||
Original [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2tUe.png)

Comment: You're falling foul of anti-aliasing. Those white-looking pixels around the border of the image aren't actually white -- they take on a bit of the color of the thing they're next to, which helps blur the edge slightly and make it look less sharp and pixellated. You'll see the same effect if you open the image in Paint and use the bucket fill tool. If you zoom closely into the image, you can see the anti-aliasing quite clearly.

Comment: Unfortunately this all means that it's not a trivial job to replace the background. You need to effectively undo the anti-aliasing to figure out what's background and what isn't, replace the background, then re-apply the anti-aliasing. It can be done (paint.net does it well for instance), but it's more complex